# Converting a HTML string to normal text using iphone dev

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, cocoa, uiwebview

how to convert a HTML string to a plain text in iphone dev. Is there any in built functions which does it ?

I am actually downloading a html string from web and showing it in the UIwebview and i am giving the user a edit option so that the html needs to converted to tet so that user can edit

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you're downloading the HTML.

I would suggest that you use `NSURLConnection` and `NSURLRequest` to form a HTTP GET request and download the HTML that way.

You should implement the delegate methods for `NSURLConneciton`. You shoudl allocate an `NSMutableData` object to store the data you download, and append new data to it in `-connection:didReceiveData:`

Then once `-connectionDidFinishLoading:` is called, you can convert your `NSData` object into an `NSString` using

```
[[NSString alloc] initWithData:myData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

This will give you the raw HTML of the page, which you can then push into a `UIWebView`, using `loadHTMLString:baseURL:` or pass into a `UITextView` with `setText:` for editing.

Comment: I think the asker rather meant how to _render_ the html output into plain text, i.e. translating <br> into a CR/LF, etc.